# iPad pro 11 (2018) exact css media query

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries

I've set an css media query for 11" iPad pro, but it's not read on iPad.

my current media query is

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width: 1194px) 
and (max-width: 1194px)
and (orientation: landscape) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{

}
```

I've working css for the 12.9" like that

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1366px) and (orientation: landscape) {
}
```

I've also check the width for 11" is 1194px on landscape, anyone know the right css media query for only ipad pro 11"?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ipad-specific-css/ can you look into this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple iPad Pro 11 (2018) Only Media Query which covers portrait to landscape width.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 834px) and (max-width: 1194px)  { /* Your Styles... */ }
```

Apple iPad Pro 11 (2018) Media Queries (In terms of Tablets only)

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)  { /* Your Styles... */ }
```

Apple iPad Pro 11 (2018) Min-Width Media Queries

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 834px) { /* Your Styles... */ }
```

Apple iPad Pro 11 (2018) Min-Height Media Queries

```css
@media only screen and (min-height: 1194px) { /* Your Styles... */ }
```

Apple iPad Pro 11 (2018) Landscape Media Queries

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1194px) and (orientation: landscape) { /* Your Styles... */ }
```

Apple iPad Pro 11 (2018) Portrait Media Queries

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 834px) and (orientation: portrait) { /* Your Styles... */ }
```

Apple iPad Pro 11 (2018) Retina Media Queries

```css
@media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
  only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 264dpi),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 
    /* Retina styles here */
}
```

Retina 2x Media Query

```css
@media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
  only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 
    /* Retina styles here */
}
```

Retina 3x Media Query

```css
@media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
  only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
  only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/1),
  only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 384dpi),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 3dppx) { 
    /* Retina styles here */
}
```

Comment: Some part of my CSS is need an iOS emulator to check is it work or not